# Why is my button not working at all when I click it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a to-do list with JS , React and HTML. The button in the HTML code:
`<input type="button" value="Add your new task" id="newTaskBtn">`
gets added with an event listener:
`document.getElementById('newTaskBtn').addEventListener("click",addTask);`
which calls the function `addTask()`:

```
function addTask(){
        if (document.getElementById('newTask').value = " ") {
            alert('You have to write something.')
        } else {
            const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('to-dos container'));
            root.render(<newTaskComponent content={document.getElementById('newTask').value}/>)
            {() => setId(c = c + 1);}
        }
    }
```

which checks if the input box:
`<input type="text" name="addNewTask" id="newTask" value=" " placeholder="Add a new task">`
is empty , if not , it calls the newTaskComponent component:

```
function newTaskComponent(props){
        return (
          <>
            <toDoId />
            <p>{props.content}</p>
            <Checkbox />
            <DeleteBtn />
          </>
        );
    }
```

which adds a checkbox, a delete button and gives the todo an id(Todo 1,Todo 2 ...)
The toDoId() component:

```
function toDoId(){
        const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
        const addTodo = () => {
            setTodos((c) => [...c]);
          };

        return(
            <>
              <h1>{addTodo}</h1>
            </>
        )
    }
```

uses the setId() function declared at the addTask() function to give the todo an Id. Then the checkbox function:

```
function Checkbox(){
        if (document.getElementById('checkbox').checked) {
            alert('Congratulations!')
        } 
        return (
            <>
            <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' id='checkbox'></input>
            <label for='checkbox'>Completed!</label>
              </>  
        )
    }
```

which congratulates you after the task is done(when checkbox checked).For the delete button:

```
 function DeleteBtn() {
        return(
            <>
            <button onClick={newTaskComponent = " " && alert(Deleted)}>Delete</button>
            </>
        )
    }
```

it deletes the newTaskComponent(base component) and alerts that the task is deleted.

I thought there was going to be to-dos after pressing the button, but it does not appear, the worst part is even the if statement which checks for blank input also does not work, it is simply like as if I did not write any code into the JS file, all source code is below and I hope a expert could give some help(also if able to explain in detail that would be better)

toDoList.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="toDoList.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="to do list">
                <form>
                    <h1>To-Do List:</h1>
<input type="text" name="addNewTask" id="newTask" value=" " placeholder="Add a new task">
                    <div id="to-dos container">
                        
                    </div>
                    <input type="button" value="Add your new task" id="newTaskBtn">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

toDoList.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

function myFunction(){
    document.getElementsByTagName('body').addEventListener("load",myFunction);
    document.getElementById('newTaskBtn').addEventListener("click",addTask);

    function DeleteBtn() {
        return(
            <>
            <button onClick={newTaskComponent = " " && alert(Deleted)}>Delete</button>
            </>
        )
    }

    function Checkbox(){
        if (document.getElementById('checkbox').checked) {
            alert('Congratulations!')
        } 
        return (
            <>
            <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' id='checkbox'></input>
            <label for='checkbox'>Completed!</label>
              </>  
        )
    }

    function toDoId(){
        const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
        const addTodo = () => {
            setTodos((c) => [...c]);
          };

        return(
            <>
              <h1>{addTodo}</h1>
            </>
        )
    }

    function newTaskComponent(props){
        return (
          <>
            <toDoId />
            <p>{props.content}</p>
            <Checkbox />
            <DeleteBtn />
          </>
        );
    }

    function addTask(){
        if (document.getElementById('newTask').value = " ") {
            alert('You have to write something.')
        } else {
            const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('to-dos container'));
            root.render(<newTaskComponent content={document.getElementById('newTask').value}/>)
            {() => setId(c = c + 1);}
        }
    }

}
```

Please help and if the question is out of stackoverflow rules ,please do not delete the question, thank you.

---

Edit: I have changed the source code after looking at stackOverflow and google , it still doesnt load after pressing the button but I hope it helps.

toDoList.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="toDoList.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body id="body" onload="myFunction()">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="to do list">
                <form>
                    <label for="addNewTask">To-Do List:</h1><br>
                    <input type="text" name="addNewTask" id="newTask" value="" placeholder="Add a new task"><br>
                    <div id="to-dos container"></div><br>
                    <input type="button" value="Add a new To-Do" id="addNewTask" onclick="addTask()">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

toDoList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

let input = document.getElementById("newTask").value ;

function myFunction(){
    function addTask(){
        if(input === ''||input === ' '){
           alert('You have to write something')
        }else{
            const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('to-dos container'))
            root.render(<NewTaskComponent />)
        }
    }
    function NewTaskComponent(){
        return(
            <div>
                <ToDoId />
                <p>{`${input}`}</p>
                <Checkbox />
                <Delete />
            </div>
        )  
    }
    function ToDoId(){
        let c = 1
    const add = (function(){
        return function () {c += 1; return c}
    })();
    add();
}

    function Checkbox(){
        return(
            <input type='checkbox' id='checkbox' onChange= {check()}></input>
        )
    }
    function check(){
        if(document.getElementById('checkbox') === true){
           alert('Congrats!')
        }else{
            alert('Remember to complete your tasks!')
        }
    }
    function Delete(){
        return(
            <input type='button' onClick= {erase()}></input>
        )
    }
    function erase(){
        del();
        decrement();
    }
    function del(){
        const container = document.getElementById('to-dos container')
        const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
        root.render(container);
        root.unmount();
    }

    const decrement = (function(){
        return function () {c -= 1; return c}
    })();
}
```

Special Thanks to Jacob!

Answer (score 0):

The first place to start will be looking into why 'the if statement which checks for blank input also does not work'.
The process will never start because your check
`if (document.getElementById('newTask').value = " ") {`
is using a single `=`, which will is assigning instead of checking.
Try changing this to `==` or `===` and see if you get much further.

Comment: I have changed the = to both == and === and tested again, but it does not help, I think it is some error in calling the function(function order , no self invoke, function not found), because I have had function errors in my past project, but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Could you add a screen shot of the errors you are getting?
One other thing that I noticed is that the `addTodo` method doesnt take in any new todos to add. I would have expected something along the lines of
`const addTodo = (addedToDo) => setTodos((c) => [...c, addedToDo])};`

Comment: I am not getting any errors in VS Code but it does say that the myFunction() is declared but never called, even after adding an event listener. The todo Id is in testing mode, and I kind off need more solutions mainly for why the button does not do anything, also I have try your suggestion but there are still no outputs.

Comment: That is because 'myFunction' is never called.
You are setting up the event listener to call `myFunction()` inside `myFunction`. Which means it will never actually be called.
You will need to setup the event listeners elsewhere

Comment: I get what you mean, but isnt the document.getElementsByTagName('body').addEventListener("load",myFunction); supposed to do that?

Comment: But `document.getElementsByTagName('body').addEventListener("load",myFunction);` is inside of the `myFunction` method. You will either need to find another place to setup the event listeners, or just use something like `<buton onclick="addTask()">`

Comment: I have tried both putting the event listener outside the function and the default button onclick syntax , it is still not running and simply updates the page , no change on data.

Comment: reloading a page is a button's default activity. You need to prevent the default by capturing the event within your listener and call its `preventDefault()` mwthod.

Comment: But doesn't `preventDefualt()` prevent the addTask() function from running ,(since it its defualt action)

Comment: And also the function(event) statement make the myFunction and addTask not run